# Difference between "одежда" and "платье"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

I'm wondering when to use one or the other, as at least based on their English translations, they are hardly distinguishable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Одежда` is any clothing in general (usually except "underwear" which is "(нижнее) бельё").

`Платье` solely means a female dress (see [images](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5)) in modern Russian. And only occasionally, in some archaic and/or poetic contexts, you'll find it used for whatever wear/dress (e.g. "новое платье короля").

Comment: I can see the goolge translate suggests that the first meaning of `платье` is "Одежда, носимая поверх белья." but it's definitely wrong for modern R. It could be that way yet at the end of XIX century, but if you use it that way today most native speakers will be confused.

Comment: Interestingly, a wardrobe is "**платяной** шкаф", even though their use is not meant to be exclusive to women. :D

Comment: "платяной шкаф" - indeed, and this is exactly the legacy of this older much wider meaning of "платье" (and probably because of that "платяной шкаф" also sounds quite archaic today - I believe most people would prefer to say "шкаф для одежды" or simply "шкаф" instead. But that could just my subjective observation - more research needed :)

Comment: While "одежда" doesn't mean "underwear", "без одежды" in some context could mean "naked, without underwear too".

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens платяной шкаф is indeed quite rare nowadays, there's another word sounding similar to wardrobe which is гардероб both as a place and as a collection, not sure how common it is, but i use it

Comment: Одежка is more or less clothing (Put ons—О (prefix) + деть (verb) + ка (ending makes it a noun)). платье is more or less garment (related to платок =piece of square fabric used to throw over the body), which is why it used to have the old meaning of clothing—something worn over your underwear (бельё whites).
So платье = garment = nowadays = dress/ одежка = clothing.

Comment: одёжка (from одёжа, which isn't a part of modern vocabulary) is not quite the same as одежда, besides the fact that it's a diminutive form of одежда, usually it means A) one piece of clothing to the exclusion of pants and headwear + B) special type of clothing, for special purpose for example a dog clothing could be called одёжка, in the meaning of одежда it's mainly features in some [proverbs](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/898630)

Comment: I meant одежда :) Basically everything I said is correct—except replace одёжка (never even heard that word) with одежда. I didn't even notice the letters being different.)

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Hi. How does "наряд" compare with these two?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens hi, "наряд" is usually either spruce or special purpose clothing, all pieces together, the adjective "нарядный" literally means spruce, the verb наряжаться - to dress up